# the angular way to store async values in local variable and display it in template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of Objects(returned from my service component). I want to read out five Objects randomly chosen out of the array and from this new data, i want to display one Object after another in the template with a delay, starting again with the first Object, when the last Object (Object Number five) has been shown. And so on...

I managed to do it as you can see below. But i didnt manage to do it with Observables or the RxJS library and i guess with those tools it might be even easier. So i just wonder whats the Angular way of doing it.

Btw iam using Angular 4.

```
service component:

getWeatherdata(): Observable<IWeatherdata[]> {
        return this.http.get("./assets/weatherdata.json")
            .map(res => {
                let data = res.json();
                return data; // the data consists of 100 Objects
            });
}
```

```
app component:

itemsWeatherdata: IWeatherdata[] = [];
weatherObject: IWeatherdata[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.handleWeatherdata();
  }

handleWeatherdata() {
    return this._searchService.getWeatherdata()
      .subscribe (res => {
        while (this.itemsWeatherdata.length <= 4) {
          let randomNum = this.randomNumber(0, 99); //randomNumber returns a whole random number between 0 and 100.
          let randomWeatherdata = res[randomNum];
          if (!this.itemsWeatherdata.includes(randomWeatherdata)) {
            this.itemsWeatherdata.push(randomWeatherdata);
          }
        }
        (function getWeatherObject(index = 0) {
          this.weatherObject[0] = this.itemsWeatherdata[index];
          index < this.itemsWeatherdata.length - 1 
          ? setTimeout(getWeatherObject.bind(this), 20000, index += 1) 
          : setTimeout(getWeatherObject.bind(this), 20000, index = 0); 
        }).bind(this)(); 
      })
    }
```

```
in the template:

<div *ngFor="let data of weatherObject">
   {{data}} 
</div>
```

**edit /***

the input is an array of Objects like so:

```
[Obj1, Obj2, Obj3, Obj4, Obj5]
```

the output is an array of only one Object where the one and only element of the array is updated with a delay of 20sec like so(it shall display every element and only one element at a time of the input array one after another and repeat itself when the last Object has been shown):

```
[Obj1] // delay 20sec
[Obj2] // delay 20sec
[Obj3] // delay 20sec
[Obj4] // delay 20sec
[Obj5] // delay 20sec
[Obj1] // delay 20sec
and so on ...
```

***/ edit**

Like i said, it works like i want it to but it seems performance-heavy. And also i just would like to know the angular way of doing this. I tried to manage it with observables and the RxJS library but just couldnt get it done with it.

So any hint what concepts or operators i should research on or use, would be appreciated, so i can give it another shot.

Or what kind of advantages are there doing it with observables or another way over my approach?

thanks from a total Newbie in Angular

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to bind Observables to the template.

```js
weatherObject: Observable<IWeatherdata[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.weatherObject = this._searchService.getWeatherdata()
      .pipe(map(res => {
        while (this.itemsWeatherdata.length <= 4) {
          let randomNum = this.randomNumber(0, 99); //randomNumber returns a whole random number between 0 and 100.
          let randomWeatherdata = res[randomNum];
          if (!this.itemsWeatherdata.includes(randomWeatherdata)) {
            this.itemsWeatherdata.push(randomWeatherdata);
          }
        }
        (function getWeatherObject(index = 0) {
          this.weatherObject[0] = this.itemsWeatherdata[index];
          index < this.itemsWeatherdata.length - 1 
          ? setTimeout(getWeatherObject.bind(this), 20000, index += 1) 
          : setTimeout(getWeatherObject.bind(this), 20000, index = 0); 
        }).bind(this)(); 
      }));
}
```

Simplified init example (extensive mapping code omitted):

```js
weatherObject: Observable<IWeatherdata[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.weatherObject = this._searchService.getWeatherdata();
}
```

Simple example template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of weatherObject | async">
   {{data}} 
</div>
```

Example template with alias and loading message:

```html
<div *ngIf="(weatherObject | async) as weather; else loading">
  <div *ngFor="let data of weather">
    {{data}} 
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
  <p>
    Loading weather stuff...
  </p>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code could be greatly simplified if you just use an "index" array:

```
    itemsWeatherData: IWeatherData[] = [];
    maxSize = 5;
    positions = new Set<number>(); // selected positions to show
    position = -1; // position to show

    ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout(() => this.position = ++this.position % this.maxSize, 2000);
        this.handleWeatherData();
    }

    handleWeatherData() {
        return this._searchService.getWeatherdata()
            .subscribe(res => this.selectRandomNumbers());
    }

    selectRandomNumbers() {
        this.position = -1;
        this.positions.clear();
        while (this.positions.size < this.maxSize) {
            this.positions.add(this.randomNumber(0, this.itemsWeatherData.length-1));
        }
    }
```

and html to show just current one of those randomly selected objects:

```
<div *ngIf="position > -1">
    {{positions[position]}}
</div>
```

and that position is changing to next every 2 seconds (as in your code)

selectRandomNumbers is the easiest and fastest way to select a small number of distinct random numbers (5) from a relatively large number (100).
For different ratio I'd use a more sophisticated method like choosing a random number from smaller array on each step...